# Twig: How to use variable in range()

Tags: twig, drupal-theming

```
{% set lower_limit = 0 %}
{% set upper_limit = 10 %}
{% for i in range(lower_limit, upper_limit) %}
  ---
{% endfor %}
```

How should we use variables in `range()`? Above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. Above code does work! Actually the variable which I was using in `range` was holding a string value. I used filter `number_format`. Now it works. Example...

```
{% set dots = item.dots|number_format %}
{% for i in range(1, dots) %}
  .
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do note you could use the `{% for i in 1..dots|number_format %}` for shorter notation